# Cake php, set flash message in current page without losing the form contents

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In cake php, is there anyway to set flash message in current page without losing form values.

Here an form is submitted, then we need to set a flash message in current page without losing form values. (No ajax /no Javascript is used)

Form Submitted goto php and set a flash message

Html

```
<div class="videos form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Video');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Add Video'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('video', array('label' => false, 'div' => false,'type' => 'file','style' =>'height:25px'));
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

PHP

```
function add()
{
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $file = $this->data['Video']['video'];
        $destination = 'files/videos/';
        $max_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024; //100 MB
        $allowed_types = array('mp4','flv','WebM','3GPP','avi','wmv','FLV','MP4','AVI','MOV');
        $status = $this->FileUpload->uploadFile($file, $destination, $max_size, $allowed_types, $filename);
        if ($status == "SUCCESS") {
            $userFile = $file['name'];
            $extension = pathinfo($userFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $saveData = array(
                'name' => $filename . '.' . $extension,
                'path' => $destination
            );
            return $saveData;
        } else {
    // If this condition enters flash message is shown, but form values are lost
            return $status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Redirecting is *not* a requirement for flash messages, they work just fine without.

Comment: I have enter some textbox elements inside the form. Flash message will be showed, but all the form elements or user inputed values in form will be lost.

Comment: I mean *code-wise*. Where you have `// here I want...`, just set `$this->Session->setFlash('foobar')`. It should work.

Comment: Yes, you are correct `else {
 $this->Session->setFlash('foobar');
            return $status;
        }`
  works fine. But how to retrieve the form values to text fields. While I tested this, text fields became blank in form after the flash message shown.

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with flash messages. Edit your question to show the relevant code regarding your form fields.

Comment: Weird, that should actually work, the usual way to set view data from controller is setting it to `$this->data` of the controller, and since you didn't redirect, whatever posted value should still be retained... Try setting the value manually in the `else` block like: `$this->data['Video']['title'] = 'test'`, see if it's set in the view upon unsuccessful upload

Answer (score 2):

When you set data to file after that line set:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('your message', true));
```

and where you want to show write in that view file:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an action that renders a View, there is no `return`, so you should remove these lines:

```
return $saveData;
return $status;
```

To interact with the View and send variables, you use the `set` method and as in this case you need the form data, you must send the variable `$this->data` again:

```
$this->set('data', $this->data);
```

And as already reported, to set a flash message:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('foobar');
```

More information:

- [Controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/955/Controllers)
- [set()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1086/set)